# Decimal to Binary Converting Years in C++

Tags: c++, binary, decimal, converters

I wrote a program that converts decimal numbers (date of birth) to binary. Converting the day and month works smoothly, but when it comes to converting the **year** a **problem occurs**, for example 2001 is converted to 2521075409 instead of 11111010001. Could you tell me where the problem is?

```
{
    int i;
    long long temp, bin;

    i = 1;
    bin = 0;
    
    printf("Number %d in binary: \n", year);
    while (year > 0) {
        temp = year % 2;            
        year /= 2;              
        bin += temp * i;        
        i *= 10;                
    }
    printf("%lld\n\n",bin);
}
```

Comment: You're overflowing the size of `bin`.

Comment: You could use ```std::bitset<>``` to binary conversion ([reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `int i;`, `i *= 10` quickly reaches the max limit for 32-bit integer `0x7fff'ffff`. So `i` will also need to be 64-bit, it can be `unsigned` so the ceiling is a bit higher at `0xffff'ffff'ffff'ffff`. Example

```
unsigned long long i = 1;
unsigned long long bin = 0;
int year = 2001;
while (year > 0) 
{
    int temp = year % 2;
    year /= 2;
    bin += temp * i;
    i *= 10;
    printf("check i: %llu\n", i);
}
printf("%016llu\n\n", bin);
```

To print larger numbers use a character buffer to save `temp` in each iteration.

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't even notice that **i** was overflowed.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively this piece of code use the `std::bitset` class from the STL library. `bitset` represents a fixed-size sequence of **N** *bits*.

```
string s = bitset<64>(2001).to_string();
     
// Strip off the leading zeroes.
const auto loc1 = s.find('1');
     
if(loc1 != string::npos) s= s.substr(loc1);

cout<<s<<endl;
```

output:

```
11111010001
```

full [example](https://godbolt.org/z/e49q69dzG)